# iOS 8 Custom Keyboard: Decimal Pad with Done Button

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, ios8-extension

I am developing iOS application on Swift and I want to add a done button to the Decimal Pad Keyboard Type. Do I need to create an Application Extension for Custom Keyboard  to recreate Decimal Pad with a done button or is there another way. I only need this keyboard to be accessible within my app. Thanks.

Comment: if you don't want a toolbar on top of the iPhone keyboard you need your own extension or custom keyboard alternative like this one https://github.com/shicang1990/SCNumberKeyBoard

Comment: I don't think so. This question is about iOS 8 custom keyboards.